# Getting the address of a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-address

My apologies, I know there are a million questions on pointers, arrays etc. although as basic as this is I just can't seem to find anything pointing (ha ha!) to an answer.

I've got a pointer that is initialised to point to a chunk of memory, I understand that I can access this memory similar to how I would an array:

```
char *mMem=new char[5000];
cout<<mMem[5]<<endl;
```

Which is actually:

```
char *mMem=new char[5000];
cout<<*(mMem+5)<<endl;
```

What I don't understand though is how to get the address of an *element* - I'm aware that element isn't quite the right word considering mMem isn't an array - that's if my understanding is correct, can't be too sure though because it seems every site uses whatever words it wants when it comes to pointers and arrays. So, if I have:

```
char *mMem=new char[5000];
cout<<mMem[5]<<endl;
    or
cout<<*(mMem+5)<<endl;
```

why does the address of operator not work correctly:

```
cout<<&mMem[5]<<endl;
```

Instead of getting the address of the 5th element, I get a print out of the memory block contents from that element onwards. So, why did the address of operator not work as I was expecting and how can I get the address of an element of the memory?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`&mMem[5]` *is* the address of the 5th element. The reason why you get a printout of the memory from there is because they type of `&mMem[5]` is `char*`, but strings in legacy C are also of `char*`, so the `<<` operator simply thinks that you want to print a string from there. I would try casting the pointer to a `void*` before printing:

```
cout << static_cast<void*>(&mMem[5]) << endl;
```

By the way, `&mMem[5]` and `mMem+5` are just the same.

Answer (score 4):

You are getting the address of element 5 as you expect, but the `cout` print functionality for a `char *` is to print out the string contents at that memory location, not the pointer value.

Cast the pointer to an int: `cout << (int)&mMem[5];` and you should get the address printed.